# django development server, how to stop it when it run in background?

Tags: python, django, server

I use a Cloud server to test my ***django*** small project, I type in `manage.py runserver` and then I log out my cloud server, I can visit my site normally, but when I reload my cloud server, I don't know how to stop the development server, I had to kill the process to stop it, is there anyway to stop the development?

Comment: This is a good question. Yes, all of us know how to kill a process but when a service provides a start option, you assume you don't know something... and look for a stop. It is rather an oversight that django breaks this paradigm.

Comment: @KateYoak Well, I sent it to Django developers.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The answer is findable via Google -- and answered in other forums. Example solution is [available on the Unix & Linux StackExchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/how-to-stop-a-background-process).

To be explicit, you could do:

```
ps auxw | grep runserver
```

This will return the process and its respective PID, such as:

```
de        7956  1.8  0.6 540204 55212 ?        Sl   13:27   0:09 /home/de/Development/sampleproject/bin/python ./manage.py runserver
```

In this particular case, the PID is `7956`. Now just run this to stop it:

```
kill 7956
```

And to be clear / address some of the comments, you have to do it this way because you're running the development server in the background (the `&` in your command). That's why there is no "built-in" Django stop option...

Comment: Can you bring the job to the foreground using 'fg' on the command line?  I toggled mine to bg then back to fg.  Then CONTROL-C stops the job altogether.  

When I start my server, it prints a few lines of text, the last being "Quit the server with CONTROL-C."

February 01, 2018 - 20:31:32
Django version 2.0.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: @the_cat_lady that is a good suggestion, too! I would say that warrants its own answer, since it's another way to do it...

Comment: Unfortunately, Django launches a child process, which makes two process, which makes it hard to kill from a script.  Especially because killing the parent does not kill the child.

Comment: "The answer is findable via Google" --> I searched on Google and found this current page, from Google :)

Answer (score 50):

One liner..

```
pkill -f runserver
```

Comment: awesome. Thats short and sweet.

Comment: **Watch out**, in case **multiple** 'runserver' processes are running!!! This will kill _all_ running "runserver" processes.

Comment: @amolbk, what is the disadvantage of doing like that ?

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: thanks very much, the only solution that works.

Answer (score 7):

Ctrl+c should work.  If it doesn't Ctrl+/ will force kill the process.

Answer (score 6):

well it seems that it's a bug that django hadn't provided a command to stop the development server . I thought it have one before~~~~~

Comment: My ISP provides a very limited shell that kicks me out on some commands, like `kill` and even `ps` :)
Though I may easily execute python manage.py ...
It's a pity to file a support ticket each time I need to execute a single command. So I agree – it's a must to be able to stop the server

Answer (score 5):

We can use the following command.

> -> netstat -ntlp

then we will get number of process running with PID, find our python server PID and Kill process.

> -> kill -9 PID

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know ctrl+c or kill process is only ways to do that on remote machine.
If you will use Gunicorn server or somethink similar you will be able to do that using Supervisor.

Comment: ctrl+c will not stop a hearty infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on windows.

Use the below command to list all connections and listening ports (-a) along with their PID (-o).

```
netstat -a -o
```

[Find the PID of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OophC.png)

Then use this to kill the process

```
taskkill /PID PUT_THE_PID_HERE /F
```

Answer (score 1):

From task manager you can end the python tasks that are running.
Now run `python manage.py runserver` from your project directory and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically using a `.bat` script in `Command Prompt` in Windows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A port=8000
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -ano ^| findstr :%port%') DO (
    SET /A processid=%%T
    TASKKILL /PID %%T /F
)
```

gives

`SUCCESS: The process with PID 5104 has been terminated.`

Answer (score -4):

You can Quit the server by hitting **CTRL-BREAK**.

Comment: Not if it’s in the background.