# PyCharm Django previous project`s server still runs after opening and running another project

Tags: django, pycharm

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open 1st project.
2. *py manage.py runserver* 
   (now I can see my Project_1 website in browser by address http://127.0.0.1:8000/).
3. CLOSE project in PyCharm and open another project.
4. Execute *py manage.py runserver* after opening 2nd project.
5. Refresh tab in browser... And WTF? I still see my 1st project page while I am already close it, opened another project and even RUNSERVER on 2th project.

I MUST see on tab http://127.0.0.1:8000/ new project webpage after *runserver*, but it does not work.

Is it PyCharm bug or something else? I am using PyCharm Pro with the latest updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows:

1. Open CMD
2. Run command `netstat -o` to get list of running processes with open ports.
3. Find the development server process by its address (for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`). You need to remember PID number.
4. Run command `Taskkill /PID #### /F`(for example `Taskkill /PID 26356 /F`) to kill the process. Where `####` is your running development server PID number.
5. Enjoy! Now the server is not running anymore after the PyCharm was closed.

On linux:

[django development server, how to stop it when it run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066366/django-development-server-how-to-stop-it-when-it-run-in-background)

Comment: Hi, I tried your step 1-4 but still my server runs for 1st django project.....