# How to configure Atom script to run main.py

Tags: python-3.x, ide, atom-editor

I recently started used Atom IDE. It feels good. The only thing that I find difficult is to setup a project profile to run. In pycharm there is Run configuration, is there something similar to it in Atom ?

I have a project with multiple classes. When ever I want to run my script,I have to go to the main.py to launch 'ctrl + i'.

Could any one help me to setup the project in a such a way, when I execute 'ctrl + i' it automatically launch's main.py instead of the py file I am calling from.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a python script in tha Atom IDE, you can either press Ctrl+Shift+B or install a package called "terminal-tab" (https://atom.io/packages/terminal-tab). This package in an integrated command prompt like cmd on windows.

Comment: Hi, i already have a terminal-tab but it is uncomfortable to go to the terminal to restart a project every time. I am looking for something like Run configuration in Pycharm, Launch.Json in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

In the top bar, under "packages", go to "script", and select "configure script".
There put in the directory in which the program is, what command to run (`python3 main.py`), and select "save as profile." The window explains itself.
Then, you should be able to run from that profile with Alt+Ctrl+Shift+B, from whatever tab you're on.

Comment: Hi this works, Is there a way to edit already saved profiles ? Secondly, when I run a script like "python manage.py runserver" for a django project, it launches the server but when I close the terminal of the script, I find the server still running at the background. Could you tell me how to stop it ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to edit saved profiles that I know of: they aren't actually stored on your computer, instead Script [serializes them](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/master/lib/script.js#L205).  Not so sure about stopping the server - I'm very new - but you might be able to find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066366/django-development-server-how-to-stop-it-when-it-run-in-background)

Comment: I'm having trouble with that, "python3 main.py" isn't recognise as an intern command, but this work from terminal. How can I deal with it ?